# Why cannot catch the inner exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I try to catch the database exception when database server is down. We use Sybase IAnywhere.

I use regular C# try catch to get the name of the database exception.

```
try
{
//code here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Logging.Log.logItem(LogType.Exception, "Exception in isDBRunning", "App_Startup::isDBRunning() ", "GetBaseException=" + ex.GetBaseException().ToString() + "\nMessage=" + ex.Message + "\nStackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace + "\nInnerException: " + ex.InnerException);
}
```

The exception print out is this:

```
GetBaseException=iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException: Database server not found
   at iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
Message=The underlying provider failed on Open.
StackTrace:    at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at Analogic.SystemSoftware.App.isDBRunning() in C:\workspace\SystemSoftware\SystemSoftware\src\startup\App.xaml.cs:line 158
InnerException: iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException: Database server not found
   at iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
```

So I think the `iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException` is the real exception I should handle. Then I added a catch for it:

```
try
{
 //code here
}
catch (iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException ex)
{
Logging.Log.logItem(LogType.Exception, "Exception in isDBRunning 1", "App_Startup::isDBRunning() ", "GetBaseException=" + ex.GetBaseException().ToString() + "\nMessage=" + ex.Message + "\nStackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace + "\nInnerException: " + ex.InnerException);
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
 Logging.Log.logItem(LogType.Exception, "Exception in isDBRunning", "App_Startup::isDBRunning() ", "GetBaseException=" + ex.GetBaseException().ToString() + "\nMessage=" + ex.Message + "\nStackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace + "\nInnerException: " + ex.InnerException);
}
```

But the `iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException` is NOT caught. I still get the `Exception` caught. why?

Comment: Can you expand on "//code here"  also, is this the code around line 158 of your app.xaml.cs file?

Comment: Also, are you *sure* this is the deployed code?

Comment: "//code here" means code to connect to database to do retrieve. And I shutdown the db server on purpose. So I will get exception from database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because what's thrown is not an SAException. Try printing out the exception directly instead of calling GetBaseException().

Answer (score 6):

`Catch` deals with the type of the actual exception that has been thrown, whereas `GetBaseException` returns the (first) `InnerException` if any exist.

Print out the actual exception to see its specific type (or inspect it in a debugger, or whatever) and then catch that.

Comment: Ah, now I see how you first can mean the same thing (first one thrown).  Well, no ambiguity now in any case.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't SAException, that's the inner exception.  It isn't clear from the stack trace what the outer exception type is.  Easy to find out with the debugger or some diagnostic code:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType().FullName;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check to see what the actual exception is that you have coming through.  Your `GetBaseException()` call might be masking the actual exception that is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to do something like this:

```
try
{
    //code here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.GetBaseException() is iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException)
    {
        // log or handle known exception
    }
    else
    {
        // log unexpected exception
    } 
}
```

As the other answers have stated, you can improve this if you know the actual type of the Exception, by changing `Exception` in the above code to the specific type of the exception.